# Consulta com um filtro diferente para cada linha

Tags: sql

Estou fazendo uma query onde, eu tenho 3 colunas relacionadas por um filtro de texto `Where '.' Like %xxx%'`, onde cada linha da coluna tem um filtro diferente (um `Like %xxx%` diferente).
Tentei montar em cases mas não consegui, segue abaixo como pensei:

```
Select `Estruturada_Duplicata`.`duplicata_comment`, `Estruturada_Duplicata`.`duplicata_value` 
from(
Select `Estruturada_Duplicata`.`duplicata_comment`, `Estruturada_Duplicata`.`duplicata_value`
Case when (duplicata_comment = '%restri%') then count(`Estruturada_Duplicata`.`duplicata_comment`), sum(`Estruturada_Duplicata`.`duplicata_value`) end restricao,
Case when (duplicata_comment = '%protesto%') then count(`Estruturada_Duplicata`.`duplicata_comment`), sum(`Estruturada_Duplicata`.`duplicata_value`) end protesto
from(`dataform`.`estruturada_duplicata`)
  )
LIMIT 1;
```

Também tentei com subqueries, mas não consegui estruturar porque só é possível trazer uma coluna por sub. Caso não tenha ficado claro no código: uma coluna da consulta só vai trazer os textos `duplicata_comment`, outra contar quantos comments existem com filtro indicado, e outra  somar o valor das duplicatas com o filtro indicado.

Answer (score 1):

Se é que eu entendi, tente:

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN (duplicata_comment = '%restri%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cont_restricao,
            SUM(CASE WHEN (duplicata_comment = '%restri%') THEN `Estruturada_Duplicata`.`duplicata_value` ELSE 0 END) val_restricao,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN (duplicata_comment = '%protesto%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) cont_protesto,
            SUM(CASE WHEN (duplicata_comment = '%protesto%') THEN `Estruturada_Duplicata`.`duplicata_value` ELSE 0 END) val_restricao
FROM `dataform`.`estruturada_duplicata`;
```

Comment: Andei testando essa solução de algumas formas, mas continua dando errado. Os counts das duplicatas sempre dão o mesmo valor, independente da condição. E a soma dos valores sempre dá zero.